# React-native Transition Speed is quite slow even after using Interaction manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am facing transition Speed issue from one Scene to another.

already tried stuff

1. InteractionManager
2. Not using touchbleopacity for transition
3. Calling async request from server in ComponentDidMount.

4.open source After interaction package is also tried " but didnt work for me."

5.Even tried Next Frame npm package "Didnt find perfect example to use it... Lokks good but getting didfficult to apply in react-native redux app.. for async request... "

Still On transition my UI freezes for 1 sec.

Any Thing more to increase speed for transition.

Thanks

Edit #adding code nOW

```
class ReviewsFeed extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        AuthHeader:'',
        renderPlaceholderOnly:true,
    };
}


componentDidMount(){
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        let realm = new Realm({
            schema: [{name: 'LoginAuth', properties: {LoginAuthKey: 'string'}}]
        });

        let backupdata = realm.objects('LoginAuth');
        let stringtoarray = backupdata[0].LoginAuthKey;
        let Authobjects = JSON.parse(stringtoarray);

        let replies = ["all"];
        let category_mentions= ["all"];
        let date_range = {
            "start":"2017-02-01",
            "end":"2017-02-28"
        };

        let nps="all";
        let properties = ["all"];
        let sources = ["all"];
        let tags = [];
        let limit = 6;
        let rating = -1;
        let skip = 0;


          // asynch request through redux            
       this.props.actions.ReviewsFeeddata(Authobjects,replies,category_mentions,date_range,nps,properties,sources,tags,limit,rating,skip);
        this.props.actions.Properties(Authobjects);
        this.setState({renderPlaceholderOnly: false});
    });
}

Issuescontainer(){
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id:'Issuescontainer'
        })
    });

}

Reviewsfeed(){
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id:'ReviewsFeed'
        })
    });
}

GuestFeedback(){
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id:'GuestFeedback'
        })
    });
}

openDrawer() {
    this.refs['myDrawer'].openDrawer();
}

_renderPlaceholderView() {

    return (
        <View>
            <ReviewsHeader opentheDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    );
}

render() {

    if (this.state.renderPlaceholderOnly == true) {
        return this._renderPlaceholderView();
    }

    var navigationView = (
        <Container style={styles.FilterBackground}>
            <Content>

                <View style={styles.FilterHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.FilterHeaderstyle}> Menu </Text>
                </View>

                <List>

                    <ListItem>
                        <Button style={styles.menubutton} light block onPress={this.Reviewsfeed.bind(this)}>
                            <Text>Reviews Feed</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </ListItem>


                    <ListItem>
                        <Button style={styles.menubutton} light block onPress={this.GuestFeedback.bind(this)}>
                            <Text>Guest Feedback</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem>
                        <Button style={styles.menubutton} light  block onPress={this.Issuescontainer.bind(this)}>
                        <Text> Issues </Text>
                        </Button>
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem>
                        <Button style={styles.menubutton} light  block>
                            <Text> Sign Out </Text>
                        </Button>
                    </ListItem>

                </List>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );

    return (
        <AfterInteractions>
        <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                             ref="myDrawer"
                             drawerWidth={300}
                             drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                             renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>

            <ReviewsHeader opentheDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} />
            <ReviewsFeedback navigator={this.props.navigator}/>


        </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
        </AfterInteractions>
    );
   }
    }
```

Comment: What navigation-library are you using? The included Navigator, I suppose? Can you try providing some more information of what is going on during the transition as well as some code samples perhaps?

Comment: Yes i am making my app for android ... and i am using Navigator.... i am gonna add my some samples of my code now....  Do you know any alternative and better Navigation library

Comment: I'd say to try building a production APK and seeing if the performance issues persist. I have experienced some issues in development builds as well (see Ahmet's answer). If they still persist and the Navigator isn't as performant as you'd like, I'd recommend looking at `NavigatorExperimental` or the fairly new [react-navigator](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) library

Comment: yes i allready tried out building apk and testing in my phone .... Not in production mode....please see the code... give more examples for me...

Comment: The `InteractionManager` seems pretty unnecessary. Especially for something this basic.  
Aside from that, I'd try out another navigation-library as I stated earlier. Other than that I don't really know anything that might help either, as is.

Comment: another library Navigation Experimental .... is that solved your problem??

Comment: Well, I've jumped on other libraries when they came out because I disliked the original Navigator. So it was more from development-reasons than functional ones.

Comment: okay....  i am using Native-base theme.... do you think it can be because of theme also...????

Answer (score 1):

this slowness is normal in the development environment. steps like console.log can cause it to slow down.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html